# JSLint has reached the limit of 1,000 errors or it is confused by earlier errors and can't continue

Tags: javascript, jslint, codekit

I'm using jsLint and CodeKit to validate my js.
The .js itself is pretty minimal, and I have overcome all the issues jsLint has reported. But this one error never seems to go away: "JSLint has reached the limit of 1,000 errors or it is confused by earlier errors and can't continue. Fix the issues above and try again.   [col. -1]" I have no clue how to overcome this.

```
/*jslint browser: true, forin: true, white: false, on: true, fragment: true, eqeqeq: true */
var app = (function (w, d) {

'use strict';

var foo = 'bar';
return {
    init : function() {
        console.log(foo); 
    }
};


})(window, document);

window.onload = app.init;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe if you show us the code...

Comment: One idea: post your code here so we can look at it.

Comment: LOL. it's just kidding

Comment: ...and here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/CEarv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some JS*H*int options (like [eqeqeq](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/236), apparently) in the `jslint` line.  It's choking there.

So change...

`/*jslint browser: true, forin: true, white: false, on: true, fragment: true, eqeqeq: true */`

... to ...

`/*jslint browser: true, forin: true, white: false */`

... and I bet it works.

**Note:** It's almost always a good idea to get a simplest case example of code that's screwing up in JSLint and paste it into [JSLint.com](http://jslint.com).  Crockford keeps that URL all but up to the minute with [JSLint's github repo](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/), and it was reporting a much more user-friendly error (`Unexpected 'on'.`) than the [unfortunate "JSLint's confused"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfrozen_Caveman_Lawyer#Recurring_humor) it was telling you.

Just to make sure there wasn't something else making JSLint think there were 1000+ errors, I changed your `white` to `true`, removed the unused `w` and `d`, and another change or two so that it'd pass linting, and this works on jslint.com:

```
/*jslint browser: true, forin: true, white: true, sloppy: true */
var app = (function () {

    'use strict';

    var foo = 'bar';
    return {
        init : function() {
            window.console.log(foo); 
        }
    };


}(window, document));

window.onload = app.init;
```

So it's probably just those JSHint-specific settings that don't work in JSLint that was borking things.